# Is it possible to get the users time zone from author or message in discord.py

Tags: python, time, discord, discord.py

is it possible to get a users time zone from a message or a user if or something like that. For example if I were to say something it would print out my time zone, this is in discord.py btw.

Thanks

Comment: With slash commands, I believe so: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=locale#discord.Locale

Comment: @EricJin `interaction.locale` only gives the language selected by the user. If someone is from Québec has FR selected, it is indistinguishable from someone from France having FR selected: two very different time zones.

Answer (score -1):

**With discord.py2.0.0**

As mention in the comments you can use [interaction.locale](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=locale#discord.Locale).

Example:

```py
    @app_commands.command(name="locale")
    async def locale(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        """Get locale of user"""
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Your locale is `{interaction.locale}`")
```

A disadvantage is that you have to use an interaction and you can only get the locale of the user doing the interaction.

Comment: This would not give the timezone, but rather the language the user has selected.